# How to make a larger difference between two columns?

Tags: tables

[image]

I want to make a larger width of the selected box between two columns.

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Parameter} & Description & Unit\\
  \toprule
\textbf{Task} & Total number of task in the system & numeric count\\
\textbf{VM} & Total number of VM in the system & numeric count\\
\textbf{Time} & Average required time to complete a task & milisec\\
\textbf{Utilization} & Resource utilization & \%\\
\textbf{VM's BW} & Bandwidth allocated for each VM & MB\\
\textbf{VM's CPU} & Number of CPU in a VM & Numeric Count\\
\textbf{Utilization Model} & CloudSim utilization model & Stochastic\\
 \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Difference performance metrics \label{tab:difMetrics}}
 \end{table}
```

Comment: `@{}` removes space at the left and right side. Use `@{\quad}` between the columns.

Comment: @Johannes_B I use `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{\quad}X@{\quad}X@{\quad}X@{\quad}}`  but not solved

Comment: What do you mean by "not solved"? Is it too small? Then use a bigger skip. Is it too large? Then use a smaller one.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}XX@{\hspace{8cm}}X@{}}`

Comment: Over 100 questions, no MWE and just a *doesn't work*. I see potential for improvement.

Comment: How about `\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}`. (The default value of this parameter is `6pt`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mismatch between the intercolumn spaces is due to the fact you're using `X` for columns that should be `l`.

You can increase the spacing between the second and third columns like it's done below, but it would be curing the symptoms rather than the disease.

In the bottom table, you see how to increase the intercolumn space for a single table (in the environment); if you want it global, set the desired width of `\tabcolsep` in the preamble. Probably you won't need to even for the present table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}XX@{\hspace{2em}}X@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameter} & Description & Unit\\
\toprule
\textbf{Task} & Total number of task in the system & numeric count\\
\textbf{VM} & Total number of VM in the system & numeric count\\
\textbf{Time} & Average required time to complete a task & milisec\\
\textbf{Utilization} & Resource utilization & \%\\
\textbf{VM's BW} & Bandwidth allocated for each VM & MB\\
\textbf{VM's CPU} & Number of CPU in a VM & Numeric Count\\
\textbf{Utilization Model} & CloudSim utilization model & Stochastic\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Difference performance metrics\label{tab:difMetrics}}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{
  @{}
  >{\bfseries}l
  X
  l
  @{}
}
\toprule
Parameter & Description & Unit\\
\toprule
Task & Total number of task in the system & numeric count\\
VM & Total number of VM in the system & numeric count\\
Time & Average required time to complete a task & milisec\\
Utilization & Resource utilization & \%\\
VM's BW & Bandwidth allocated for each VM & MB\\
VM's CPU & Number of CPU in a VM & Numeric Count\\
Utilization Model & CloudSim utilization model & Stochastic\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Difference performance metrics}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]